# Math.Round odd behaviour on one customer pc

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I have a very strange problem which is occurring on only one pc out of my many customers. I have tracked it down to the the `Math.Round` method.

On this brand new win7 pc **`Math.Round(1.59999,2)`** returns **`1.59`**! 
It should be **`1.6`** and it is in all other cases.

I understand the quirks of `Math.Round` with regard to bankers rounding and I'm also aware of the various midpointrounding options in the overloads, but in any case `1.59999` should certainly always be `1.6`.

We have tried repairing the .NET Framework (3.5 sp1) on the PC and doing a full virus scan. What could be the cause of this behavior and how might I further investigate the problem.

Comment: What differences did you find on that specific computer? Regional settings? Currency, country settings, decimals and such.

Comment: @Jonas. Yes, I did check the regional settings and all appear to be default UK.

Comment: @Tim. Thanks for the edit on my question Tim. New to SO, so just learning the correct format to post.

Comment: @StructSoftDev: Welcome to SO. Here are more informations how to format properly: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/147438

Comment: Perhaps its less to do with the behaviour of `Math.Round` and more to do with precision of `double`

Comment: Please post a complete example, including your conversion to string. Posting the *exact* value before and after rounding would be useful too.

Comment: Probably relevant: [C# rounding differently depending on platform?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47302758/11683)

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I would look at is where the number `1.59999` is coming from.

Is it the result of a string which is being parsed to a float before sending to `Math.Round`? If so, could it be that that string is being truncated? Can you be sure that the value passed to `Math.Round` is in fact `1.59999` and not `1.59`?

Comment: Hi Jamiec,  Thanks for your response.  I'm certain that the value being passed to the math.round is not truncated. I placed a condition in the software to check for this bad rounding and output the values of the variable involved to the event viewer.  Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Your core issue is that you're `double` but you expect meaningful decimal digits. If decimal digits are meaningful,

I also suspect that the main difference isn't introduces when rounding: You'll always get a value very close to, but not identical to `1.6`. `1.6` is not representable exactly with `double`. It's possible you only get slightly different values on different PCs, especially if some other dll in the same process changed the floating point flags.

I suspect that the observed difference happens in your conversion to string.

Comment: I suspect the same but, its hard to tell with certainty from the question.

Comment: Thank you guys.  For the string representation of the return values from `Math.Round` I used both `.ToString` which produced "1.59". I also used `.ToString("0.00")`, which should round any non exact double of `1.6` to produce the string value of "1.60", but it doesn't - I still get "1.59". I will investigate some more on the line of double to string conversion.