# Why does Math.Round() round differently depending on the architecture (x86 vs. x64)?

Tags: c#, .net, rounding, x86-64

I noticed that the Math.Round() returns different values depending on the platform in which it is used.

I have already read the following discussion [C# rounding differently depending on platform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47302758/c-sharp-rounding-differently-depending-on-platform) ,  but I still can't explain what happens in this simple case

Here the code:

```
float c = (float)0.3;
int rounded= (int)Math.Round(c * 255);
```

If I build at x86 `rounded` is equal to 77, if I build at x64 `rounded` is equal to 76.

Comment: Why does it not explain it? That question shows you why the value can be different, [so](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/11683) it's slightly below 76.5 in one case and slightly over in another.

Comment: The linked question **does** explain the behaviour, given that there is no overload of `Math.Round()` taking a `float`, but only `double`. There is an implicit cast from `float` to `double`, so you do call `Math.Round(double)` and the duplicate question applies.

Comment: The decimal value for 3 / 10 has no exact representation in binary. Just like 3 / 7 has no exact representation in decimal.  The value must be approximated and that takes a dependency on the way the processor stores the value.  Which is platform dependent, 32-bit code uses the legacy FPU that stores values with extended precision, 64-bit code uses modern SSE instructions that don't extend precision.  Inevitably that can produce a different calculation result.  Neither 76 nor 77 are wrong, use the Decimal type to avoid surprises.