# Why is dotnet core parsing doubles differently than .net framework

Tags: c#, parsing, .net-core, double, .net-4.8

Consider the following program

```
    public static void Main()
    {
        double result = 0;
        if (Double.TryParse("29.97999999999999", NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out result)) {         
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
    }
```

When run in .net framework (x64) it prints [29.98](https://dotnetfiddle.net/X6yg6X) whereas in .net core it prints [29.97999999999999](https://dotnetfiddle.net/e3Z4oT).

Any idea why that is? And more important, how can I force one of the frameworks to round like the other and vice-versa?

Comment: i would guess it's because they [changed floating point handling in .net core 3.0](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/floating-point-parsing-and-formatting-improvements-in-net-core-3-0/) - and i don't think there's a switch to force one behaviour. but then again: why would you need one? floats should always be treated as inherently imprecise, because that's what they are; if you need arbitrary precision, better use `Decimal`

Comment: This problem is discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60147860/rounding-issues-net-core-3-1-vs-net-core-2-0-net-framework. It does not have an accepted answer though.