# Converting Decimal to Double in C# .netCore Regression from .Net4.7?

Tags: .net, parsing, .net-core

The following code seems to work fine in .NET 4.7.2, but stops working in .NET core :

(tested with https://dotnetfiddle.net/ )

```cs
Console.WriteLine(decimal.ToDouble(10500000000.000000000000m));
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToDouble(10500000000.000000000000m));
Console.WriteLine((double)10500000000.000000000000m);
```

Before it correctly returned `10500000000`, now it is returning `10499999999.999998`

Am I missing something?

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65266396/why-is-dotnet-core-parsing-doubles-differently-than-net-framework) has a comment linking to a .NET Core 3.0 change https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/floating-point-parsing-and-formatting-improvements-in-net-core-3-0/ That could probably be why

Comment: Indeed, parsing 10500000000m works.

Comment: `Before it correctly returned 10500000000` - it didn't though, did it? This code does not return anything, it prints to console. The actual `double` value that is returned by the three conversion methods [was, in fact](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qEjfNz), `10499999999.999998` in .NET 4.7.2 too.

Comment: that's a good point.

Comment: It seems to be depends on the number of 0 after the dot :
This works :
Console.WriteLine(decimal.ToDouble(10500000000.00000000000m).ToString("R"));
not this :
Console.WriteLine(decimal.ToDouble(10500000000.000000000000m).ToString("R"));

Comment: yes it does, thank you for the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like .NET Core has a higher precision than .NET 4.7.2 and that's why you have a difference.

You can try to round your `double` to avoid getting this result.

```cs
decimal value = 10500000000.000000000000m;
double rounded = decimal.ToDouble(decimal.Round(value, 0));
Console.WriteLine(rounded); // Output: 10500000000
```